# Pandas: convert object to str

Tags: pandas, string, object, types

I have the following dataframe:

```
    R_fighter       B_fighter           win_by                  last_round  Referee         date            Winner
0   Adrian Yanez    Gustavo Lopez       KO/TKO                  3           Chris Tognoni   March 20, 2021  Adrian Yanez
1   Trevin Giles    Roman Dolidze       Decision - Unanimous    3           Herb Dean       March 20, 2021  Trevin Giles
2   Tai Tuivasa     Harry Hunsucker     KO/TKO                  1           Herb Dean       March 20, 2021  Tai Tuivasa
3   Cheyanne Buys   Montserrat Conejo   Decision - Unanimous    3           Mark Smith      March 20, 2021  Montserrat Conejo
4   Marion Reneau   Macy Chiasson       Decision - Unanimous    3           Mark Smith      March 20, 2021  Macy Chiasson
```

I'm trying to convert the type of the column **win_by** from `object` to `str`. 
I use `.astype()` as suggested here [How to convert column with dtype as object to string in Pandas Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33957720/how-to-convert-column-with-dtype-as-object-to-string-in-pandas-dataframe):

```
UFC_db['win_by'] = UFC_db['win_by'].astype('|S')
```

but nothing changed:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 6012 entries, 0 to 6011
Data columns (total 7 columns):
 #   Column      Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------      --------------  ----- 
 0   R_fighter   6012 non-null   object
 1   B_fighter   6012 non-null   object
 2   win_by      6012 non-null   object
 3   last_round  6012 non-null   object
 4   Referee     6012 non-null   object
 5   date        6012 non-null   object
 6   Winner      6012 non-null   object
dtypes: object(7)
memory usage: 328.9+ KB
```

I also tried

```
UFC_db['win_by'] = UFC_db['win_by'].astype('str')

UFC_db['win_by'] = UFC_db['win_by'].astype(str)
```

and

```
UFC_db['win_by'] = UFC_db['win_by'].astype('str',errors ="ignore")
```

as suggested here [Python - pandas column type casting with "astype" is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52240694/python-pandas-column-type-casting-with-astype-is-not-working)

but still nothing changed

Comment: Have you tried UFC_db['win_by'] = UFC_db['win_by'].astype("|S")

Comment: Yes CaseyKnight, it was my first try!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize that `object` is not a problem, instead is the type that pandas use for string or mixed types (https://pbpython.com/pandas_dtypes.html). More precisely:

| Pandas dtype | Python type | NumPy type | Usage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| object | str or mixed | string_, unicode_, mixed types | Text or mixed numeric and non-numeric values |
| int64 | int | int_, int8, int16, int32, int64, uint8, uint16, uint32, uint64 | Integer numbers |
| float64 | float | float_, float16, float32, float64 | Floating point numbers |

Infact if I print the type of a single cell it gives me `str`

```
type(UFC_db.at[0,'Referee'])
```

> str

and as a string I can change it with another string

```
UFC_db.at[0,'Referee'] = 'XXXXXX'
UFC_db.at[0,'Referee']
```

> 'XXXXXX'

Answer (score 2):

I tried many methods, but I found that this is the only method that worked for me and convert the object into text

```
df['column'].astype('string')
```