# pandas: converting dataframe column to int following dataframe manipulation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

*Running pandas 1.5.3. Also attempted on pandas 2.2.1.*

I am loading in data from a CSV that looks like such:

```
888|0|TEST ACCOUNT
888|1|Sample Ship-to
802001|0|COMPANY 1
802001|1|COMPANY 1 INC
802001|2|COMPANY 1 BALL
K802001|3|COMPANY 1
```

With columns `CUSNO`, `S2`, and `NAME`, in that order.

I have a script that loads in the data, then checks the first column and makes sure it is of `int64` in the resulting DataFrame. If not, the script is supposed to convert the column to numeric and drop the rows that have NaN in them.

So, before:

```
     CUSNO  S2            NAME
0      888   0    TEST ACCOUNT
1      888   1  Sample Ship-to
2   802001   0       COMPANY 1
3   802001   1   COMPANY 1 INC
4   802001   2  COMPANY 1 BALL
5  K802001   3       COMPANY 1
```

Then run:

```
cl['CUSNO'] = pd.to_numeric(cl.CUSNO, errors='coerce')
cl = cl.dropna(axis='index', how='any')
```

After:

```
      CUSNO  S2            NAME
0     888.0   0    TEST ACCOUNT
1     888.0   1  Sample Ship-to
2  802001.0   0       COMPANY 1
3  802001.0   1   COMPANY 1 INC
4  802001.0   2  COMPANY 1 BALL
```

I want to make `CUSNO` a column full of `int64` or similar types, but when I run `company_locations['CUSNO'].dtype` it keeps returning `float64`. (Realistically, I want to get rid of the decimal point at the end of every entry in `CUSNO` and thought typecasting to `int` or similar would work best.)

I've tried a number of solutions, namely:

```
cl['CUSNO'] = pd.to_numeric(cl.CUSNO, errors='coerce').dropna().astype(int) # replacing the earlier line 1 of the script
cl['CUSNO'] = cl.astype({'CUSNO': 'int'})
cl['CUSNO'] = cl['CUSNO'].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

I've tried `inplace=True` for line 2 in the script above. I've also tried solutions from [pandas: to_numeric for multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36814100/pandas-to-numeric-for-multiple-columns), [Change column type in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891038/change-column-type-in-pandas), and [Python - pandas column type casting with "astype" is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52240694/python-pandas-column-type-casting-with-astype-is-not-working).

Perhaps I'm missing something here? Do I have to copy the new DataFrame to a new variable or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think simple (after dropping the `NaNs`):

```py
df["CUSNO"] = df["CUSNO"].astype(int)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    CUSNO  S2            NAME
0     888   0    TEST ACCOUNT
1     888   1  Sample Ship-to
2  802001   0       COMPANY 1
3  802001   1   COMPANY 1 INC
4  802001   2  COMPANY 1 BALL
```

Comment: Much appreciated--I think I had tried this earlier before running the `dropna` and it kept throwing errors. Got it working now.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `pd.to_numeric`, it has a `NaN` value, which makes the entire row's dtype become `float`.

After you remove tha `NaN`, you can run this an it will be converted back into `int`:

```
cl["CUSNO"] = cl["CUSNO"].astype(int)
```

```
    CUSNO  Index     Description
0     888      0    TEST ACCOUNT
1     888      1  Sample Ship-to
2  802001      0       COMPANY 1
3  802001      1   COMPANY 1 INC
4  802001      2  COMPANY 1 BALL
```

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

if you want `int` dtype with NaN, use following code:

```
cl['CUSNO'] = pd.to_numeric(cl['CUSNO'], errors='coerce').astype('Int64')
cl = cl.dropna()
```

`astype('Int64')` can make int with Na